# Create cookies for jquery popup

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, setcookie

I'm am new to creating cookies and need to create two for a jquery popup.

The first:
- cookie_name = newsletter_displayed - value should be a date, expiration 1 month
- If newsletter_displayed is set don't show until 4 minutes has passed.

The second:
- newsletter_suppressed - value should be a date (the date that the X button was clicked or they subscribed), expiration should be 1 month
- if newsletter_suppressed is set don't display ad.

My html

```
<div class="slide">    
    <div id="dialog">
        <div id="close">x</div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <p class="text-center">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER TO RECEIVE EXCLUSIVE DISCOUNTS AND INDUSTRY NEWS.</p>
            <div class="input-group"> 
                <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter-email" class="required-entry validate-email input-text form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address..."> 
            </div> 
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default form-control text-center" type="submit">Subscribe <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $(".slide").delay(3000).animate({width:'toggle'}, 750);
    });
    $("#close").click(function() {
        $(".slide").fadeOut();
    });
});`
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $cookie_name = "newsletter_displayed";
    $cookie_value = new Date();
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        //don't show until 4 mins has passed ;
    }
?>

<?php
    $cookie_name = "newsletter_suppressed";
    $cookie_value = new Date();
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        //don't display ad ;
    }
?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? At the moment this is very much a 'write my code for me' type of question

Comment: <?php
$cookie_name = "newsletter_displayed";
$cookie_value = new Date();
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
?>
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    //don't show until 4 mins has passed
    ;
} 
?>




<?php
$cookie_name = "newsletter_suppressed";
$cookie_value = new Date();
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
?>
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    //don't display ad
    ;
} 
?>

Comment: That is what I have been able to create. I'm not sure where to go from there.